# anchor links in rails are generated but intermittently work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, anchor, passenger

I'm using Rails 5.0 with Phusion Passenger.

I am generating anchor links the documented way:

```
faq_url(anchor: 'Privacy')
```

Which creates, as expected:

```
http://stamp.marginalhacks.com/faq#Privacy
```

(You can see the links generated at the bottom of http://stamp.marginalhacks.com)

On the FAQ page I have the named anchor:  `<a name='Privacy'>PRIVACY POLICY</a>`

All of this should work, but it *usually* does not, at least not on Chrome on Ubuntu or Safari on iPad.  Usually it just goes to the top of the page.

Sometimes if I try to reload the page by hitting enter in the URL bar then it will jump to the anchor, sometimes it will not.

It seems to work fine every time with the URL:

```
http://stamp.marginalhacks.com/faq/#Privacy
```

(Note the trailing '/' before the anchor)

But this isn't the correct routing.

Is this some kind of browser issue?  Looking at the URL it generates it seems that all the characters are correct.  Is this a browser issue?  A Phusion issue?  A rails issue?  A Dave-isn't-typing-anchors-right issue?

Comment: Anchors don't have to be in `a` tags, try removing it and putting the name on the `dt` tag.

Comment: Didn't work, see:  http://stamp.marginalhacks.com/faq#Logout

The name is on the dt tag.